# Why does segmentation fault arise in fortran under calling subroutine nested gradually in two functions with double precision?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to call subroutine SPLEV of FITPACK library through two functions ('wer' and 'qwe') nested one into another (the code is below).

The following message appears under execution of compiled program:

> QWE
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
>
> Backtrace for this error:
>
> 0  0x7F3EE4BF3E08
>
> 1  0x7F3EE4BF2F90
>
> 2  0x7F3EE453A4AF
>
> 3  0x4041B6 in splev_
>
> 4  0x400BD0 in value.3386 at pr.f90:?
>
> 5  0x400A6B in MAIN__ at pr.f90:?
>
> Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

If I compile my program with flags `-g -fbacktrace -fsanitize=address,zero,undefined` the follow  output message appears:

> QWE
>
> 0.37051690837706980
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
>
> Backtrace for this error:
>
> 0  0x7FAB5F45CE08
>
> 1  0x7FAB5F45BF90
>
> 2  0x7FAB5EDA34AF
>
> 3  0x4075F0 in splev_ at splev.f:73 (discriminator 2)
>
> 4  0x400DDE in value.3386 at pr.f90:87
>
> 5  0x400FFA in qwe.3406 at pr.f90:43
>
> 6  0x400F88 in wer.3403 at pr.f90:48
>
> 7  0x400D08 in MAIN__ at pr.f90:38
>
> Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

If I compile my program with flags `-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` the follow  output message appears:

> QWE
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
>
> Backtrace for this error:
>
> 0  0x7F2BE6F0FE08
>
> 1  0x7F2BE6F0EF90
>
> 2  0x7F2BE68564AF
>
> 3  0x4075F0 in splev_ at splev.f:73 (discriminator 2)
>
> 4  0x400DDE in value.3386 at pr.f90:87
>
> 5  0x400C46 in MAIN__ at pr.f90:35
>
> Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

If I compile my program with flags `-g -fbacktrace -fsanitize=address` the follow  output message appears:

> QWE
>
> ASAN:SIGSEGV
>
> =================================================================
>
> ==4796==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x000000408f67 bp 0x7ffe7a134440 sp 0x7ffe7a1341e0 T0)
>
> 0 0x408f66 in splev_ /home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/splev.f:73
>
> 1 0x40145d in value.3386 (/home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/curfit+0x40145d)
>
> 2 0x4011a3 in intcoll /home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/pr.f90:35
>
> 3 0x401849 in main /home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/pr.f90:2
>
> 4 0x7fcad9b3282f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
>
> 5 0x400d38 in _start (/home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/curfit+0x400d38)
>
> AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
>
> SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/yurchvlad/Science/Coll_Int/F90/f90DP/1/splev.f:73 splev_
>
> ==4796==ABORTING

Firstly I will show the code and then I will give some information about subroutines CURFIT and SPLEV of library FITPACK which are playing there a principal role.

Here is my code. This is just a test program, i.e. it is not confusion, that I interpolate there array of values of analytical function.

```
PROGRAM IntColl
    USE Constants
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER  :: i, nen                    ! i = counter
                                          ! nen, nmn, ne is sirvice variables, which
                                          ! appear on exit of CURFIT and needed on entry
                                          ! of SPLEV and SPLINT

    REAL(DP) :: foo
    REAL(DP) :: MOM1                      ! dimensionless neutrino momentum

    REAL(DP) :: dmg ( 1 : 2 * NG)         ! dimensionless momentum grid
    REAL(DP) :: endf( 1 : 2 * NG)         ! electron neutrino     distribution function
                                          ! muon     neutrino     distribution function
                                          ! electron and positron distribution function

    REAL(DP) :: ten ( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1) ! service arrays:
                                          ! ten is array arising on exit of working of CURFIT
                                          ! and contain knots of the spline (for endf, mndf and edf correspondingly).
    REAL(DP) :: cen ( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1) ! needed on entry of SPLEV and SPLINT
                                          ! cen appear on exit of CURFIT, contain coefficients of spline
                                          ! (for endf, mndf and edf correspondingly) and needed on entry of SPLEV and SPLINT.
    REAL(DP) :: w   ( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1) ! w is array of weights for points on entry of CURFIT.

    DO i = 1, 2 * NG
        dmg(i)  = i / 10.D+00             ! filling arrays to give their
        endf(i) = eq_nu_di_fu(dmg(i))     ! on entry into subroutine
        w(i)    = 1.d+00                  ! CURFIT
    END DO

    MOM1 = .53D+00
    PRINT *, 'QWE'
    CALL spline(dmg, endf, nen, ten, cen)
    foo  = value(MOM1, ten, nen, cen)
    PRINT *, foo

    PRINT *, wer(MOM1)
CONTAINS

REAL(DP) FUNCTION qwe(q)           ! qwe and wer is "wrappers" for using
    REAL(DP) :: q                  ! of subroutines spline > curfit
    qwe = value(q, ten, nen, cen)  ! in main program
END FUNCTION qwe

REAL(DP) FUNCTION wer(q)
    REAL(DP) :: q
    wer = qwe(q)
END FUNCTION wer

SUBROUTINE spline(x, y, n, t, c)  ! spline is "hand-made wrapper" for 
    IMPLICIT NONE                 ! more convenient using of subroutine
                                  ! CURFIT in main program
    INTEGER             :: m, nest, n, lwrk, ier
    INTEGER,  PARAMETER :: iopt = 0
    INTEGER             :: iwrk( 1 : 10 * NG )

    REAL(DP)            :: xb, xe, fp
    REAL(DP)            :: wrk( 1 : 2 * NG * (k + 1) + (2 * NG + k + 1) * (7 + 3 * k) )
    REAL(DP)            :: x( 1 : 2 * NG), y(1: 2 * NG )
    REAL(DP)            :: t( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1 )
    REAL(DP)            :: c( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1 )

    xb = 0.d+00
    xe = x(2 * NG)
    m  = 2 * NG
    nest = m + k + 1
    lwrk = 2 * NG * (k + 1) + nest * (7 + 3 * k)

    CALL curfit(iopt, m, x, y, w, xb, xe, k, s, nest, n, t, c, fp, wrk, lwrk, iwrk, ier)

END SUBROUTINE spline

REAL(DP) FUNCTION value(q, t, n, c) ! value is "hand-made wrapper" for 
    IMPLICIT NONE                   ! more convenient using of subroutine
                                    ! SPLEV in main program
    INTEGER            :: n, ier    ! SPLEV should work only after
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m = 1     ! CURFIT edned its working

    REAL(DP)           :: q
    REAL(DP)           :: t( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1 )
    REAL(DP)           :: c( 1 : 2 * NG + k + 1 )
    REAL(DP)           :: ddmg(1), sddmg(1)

    ddmg(1) = q

    CALL splev(t, n, c, k, ddmg, sddmg, m, ier)

    value = sddmg(1)

END FUNCTION value

REAL(DP) FUNCTION eq_nu_di_fu(y)     ! eq_nu_di_fy givev values for array
    IMPLICIT NONE                    ! to interpolate
    REAL(DP) :: y
    eq_nu_di_fu = 1 / (EXP(y) + 1)
END FUNCTION eq_nu_di_fu

END PROGRAM IntColl
```

The module Constants is there:

```
MODULE CONSTANTS
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: DP = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15, 307)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: NG = 200                   ! NUMBER OF KNOTS OF GRID
    INTEGER , PARAMETER :: K  = 3                     ! THE ORDER OF SPLINE
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: S  = 0.D+00                ! CUBIC SPLINE SMOOTHING FACTOR
END MODULE
```

Now, subroutines CURFIT and SPLEV appearing in above code with all their dependensies are in follow sources:

https://github.com/jbaayen/fitpackpp/tree/master/fitpack

where these subroutines are in double precision

and

http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/

where these subroutines are in single precision.

It is very important to mention that with single precision above scheme works!

Of course, if I use subroutines of single precision I modify all the types of all variables in corrisponding way.

What else have I observed:

1. straightforward using of FUNCTION value works.
2. If the line
   PRINT *, 'QWE'
   of the main program is commented, the value 'foo' also is not printed.

Comment: Use compiler checks to identify bugs. You can find many yourself. Try: `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` and also `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fsanitize=address,zero,undefined`. Compile your code with these options, re-run it and report the results.

Comment: @Vladimir F    `-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` returns `fpcurf.f:186:35:

         if(fpold-fp.gt.acc) npl1 = rn*fpms/(fpold-fp)
                                   1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]` and `-g -fbacktrace -fsanitize=address,zero,undefined` returns `gfortran: error: unrecognized argument to -fsanitize= option: ‘zero’`

Comment: What happens if you run the program compiled with those flags?

Comment: @Ian Bush
if I run the program compiled with those flags the same result is returned

Comment: I seriously doubt the output was *exactly* the same, there should at least be line numbers in the backtrace. Try removing the "zero" from the sanitize flag. If needed, remove also the "undefined" and re-rurn.

Comment: @Vladimir F I am really sorry!!! It returns somewhat different message: `Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FC38766DE08
#1  0x7FC38766CF90
#2  0x7FC386FB44AF
#3  0x407D5B in splev_ at splev.f:73 (discriminator 2)
#4  0x4013E2 in value.3523 at IntColl.f90:107
#5  0x401107 in f_nu_e.3497 at IntColl.f90:144
#6  0x401079 in MAIN__ at IntColl.f90:53
Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)`

Comment: [edit] the question

Comment: @IanBush I'm sorry, actually a somewhat different message is returned after compiling with those flags. I have brought the new output in my above comment.

Comment: @VladimirF done.

Comment: Edited outputs one more time. Previous outputs were for somewhat differen version of the program.

Comment: Did you notice that SPLEV has 8 arguments in Dierckx's library and 9 in Baayen's modified library? So basically SPLEV does not receive an `ier` argument (the 8th argument is now e), however the first executable instruction in the subroutine is `ier = 10`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, thank you! This is that what was the problem. I had missed parameter "e" in new interface of subroutine SPLEV. Thank you very much.